# console UI tool for resolving merge conflicts in git... like vimdiff but 'easier'

Tags: git, conflict, mergetool

i'm looking for a console UI tool for resolving merge conflicts in git... like vimdiff but 'easier'

Answer (score 1):

I stayed with `vimdiff`, but I usually keep only the file to open visible (run `:only` when on this window), and then I disable the diff colors (which most of the time hurt the eyes) with `:diffoff`.

Finally, I have the following mapping which helps me to browse through the conflict markers:

```
nnoremap <space>n /^\(<<<<\\|====\\|>>>>\)<CR>
```

In normal mode, press `<space>n` and it will search for the markers, then use `n` to go from marker to marker.

From this point, I then edit my conflicts until I am happy.

Answer (score 0):

The [`threesome.vim`](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/threesome.vim) vim plugin provides a friendlier merge tool than vanilla vimdiff.

Regarding the comment about seeing which files are going to change when you `git pull`: `git diff --stat HEAD..origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)` after a `git fetch` will tell you that. (Substitute `--name-only` for `--stat` if you really just want the names and nothing else. Or omit `--stat` altogether to see the actual incoming diffs) You'll likely want to add an alias for this in your global configuration file.

Answer (score -2):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but `git stash` is very helpful for resolving merges. Just do:

```
git stash create
git pull
git stash pop <stashnum>
```

Where `<stashnum>` is the output from `git stash create`

Comment: i use git stash a lot, thanks.

is there a simple way to know which files will be updated in the next 'git pull' ?